# RStudio access from browser

Tags: r, linux, browser, ubuntu-18.04, rstudio-server

I installed RStudio on Linux server Ubuntu 18.04 and I couldn't access it from browser. I used
:8787 and I got the error

```
This site can’t be reached
ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

I unable firewall and still the same error. when I run

```
$sudo rstudio-server verify-installation
```

I got error

```
11 Jul 2020 14:53:12 [rsession-rstudio-server] ERROR system error 13 (Permission denied) [path: 
/home/rstudio-server/.config/rstudio/dictionaries/custom, target-dir: ]; OCCURRED AT 
rstudio::core::Error rstudio::core::FilePath::createDirectory(const string&) const 
src/cpp/shared_core/FilePath.cpp:634; LOGGED FROM: std::vector<std::__cx
```

I am new to both Linux and Rstudio. any help to figure this problem
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Which version of RStudio Server do you use ?

I had similar problem on (1.3.959) on Ubuntu 18.04. I installed the latest from https://rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download-server/debian-ubuntu/.

```
wget https://download2.rstudio.org/server/bionic/amd64/rstudio-server-1.3.1056-amd64.deb
sudo gdebi rstudio-server-1.3.1056-amd64.deb
```

After that I also need to restart apache2.service:

```
systemctl restart apache2.service
```

```
$ rstudio-server version
1.3.1056 (Water Lily) for Ubuntu Bionic
```

And after works fine.

Also good sources:

- https://community.rstudio.com/t/rstudio-server-instal-on-ubuntu-does-not-create-home-directory-home-rstudio-server/69785
- https://community.rstudio.com/t/problem-rstudio-server-installed-in-ubuntu20-04/68506